# ordering red and blue balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have $n≥1$ blue balls and $m≥1$ red balls (both $n$ and $m$ are integers). We want to put these balls into $n+m$

numbered slots. So the order matters but you can't distinguish between two red balls or two blue balls.

```
How many ways are there to do so?
Is there any simple way to generate all the permutations? An algorithm?
```

(alternatively we can think about all the binary numbers with $n$
$1$ digits and m $0$ digits when we can have 0 in the leading digits locations.

Comment: i could not understand your question , can you be more specific

Comment: An arrangement is completely determined once you know where the blue (or red) balls are, so there are $\binom{n+m}n=\binom{n+m}m$ arrangements. Generating them is essentially generating all $n$-element subsets of a set of cardinality $n+m$; see [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=generate+all+subsets+of+a+fixed+size).